# Right Indent on Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a tablix object with 3 numeric columns which is right justfied.
In my current design the numeric values in my tablix are right justified, but I need to add a space in the end of each value so it it not scrunched on the right border.

How can i add a right indentation on numeric value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Propeties window for the textboxes that you want to indent. Under Alignment, there is an Indent section, which contains an option for RightIndent.